# Continuity in $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: continuity

We know that continuity along all directions does not imply that the function is continuous in multivariate space. Intuitively is it right to think that a function can be discontinuous along a particular path even if it is continuous in all directions?

Can we say a function $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ is continuous at a given point $p\in\mathbb R^n$ if there exists an open set containing $p$ such that $f(x)$ is continuous along each direction $x_1,....,x_n$ at each point in p?

Comment: Just for clarification, are you asking that:
Given $f(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ that is continuous at a point $p$ along any straight path through $p$, can there be a path through $p$ such that $f$ restricted to the path is discontinuous?

Comment: @chriseur I know that a function can be discontinuous along a path even if it is continuous along all lines passing through it. Bit i want to know whether the converse is true( Can we prove continuity at a point p by proving that the function is continuous along each path passing through p )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. $$  \frac{x^2 y}{x^4 + y^2},   $$ evaluated along any line $y=mx$ through the origin, does approach $0.$ Indeed, for nonzero $m,x$ we get
$$ \left| \frac{m x^3}{x^4 + m^2 x^2} \right| \leq  \left| \frac{x}{m} \right|  $$ with constant $m.$ We also take the function as $0$ along the $x$ and $y$ axes. If you wish, define the function to be, for example, $0$ at the origin. That seems sensible, at least it gives substance to the idea that the function is continuous along lines through the origin.

However, along the curved path
$$  y = x^2  $$
the function stays exactly $1/2,$ and  along the curved path
$$  y = -x^2  $$
the function stays exactly $-1/2.$

That is, there is no value for the function at the origin that would make the thing continuous.

Comment: @Will Jagy: The function given does not approach 0 along any line $y=mx$; your are saying that $\displaystyle \frac{mx^3}{x^4+ m^2x^2} \to 0$ as $x\to 0$.

Comment: @chriseur It does. You can write that as $\dfrac{mx}{x^2 + m^2}$ (for the purpose of finding the limit), which is zero divided by non-zero.

Comment: @Vinay: yes, when $m\neq 0$, but the function you've written is clearly not continuous at the origin ($x,m = 0$) (see the answer below)

Comment: @chriseur Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the example, but the answer says the function "approaches $0$" as $x \to 0$, meaning the limit is $0$, which is correct. Of course the value of the function is not defined at the origin, so the function is not continuous.

Comment: The example should be completed by saying that the value of the function at $(0,0)$ is $0$. On any line through $(0,0)$ the limit is $0$, but the function is not continuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: @Vinay: yikes, I stand corrected (as I've found some egregious error in my thinking).  I apologize for disruption I may have caused.

Comment: @chriseur, I put in a few extra notes in the answer. I was asleep for most of the comments above.