# Two-dimensional limit, is my approach correct?

Tags: limits, polar-coordinates

The limit is
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^3y}{x^4+y^2}$$
As usual, I tried checking along particular paths, namely the axes and the curves $y=mx^n$ for various values of $n$, but to no avail; all the limits evaluate to $0$. I resorted to converting to polar coordinates, giving
$$\lim_{r\to0^+}\frac{r^4\cos^3t\sin t}{r^2\left(r^2\cos^4t+\sin^2t\right)}$$
In an attempt to apply the squeeze theorem, I found that trig expression in the numerator is bounded, with $|\cos^3t\sin t|\le\dfrac{3\sqrt3}{16}$, and that in the denominator I have
$$\begin{align*}
|r^2\cos^4t+\sin^2t|&\le r^2|\cos^4t|+|\sin^2t|\\
&\le r^2+1
\end{align*}$$
and so
$$\lim_{r\to0^+}\frac{r^4\cos^3t\sin t}{r^2\left(r^2\cos^4t+\sin^2t\right)}=\frac{3\sqrt3}{16}\lim_{r\to0^+}\frac{r^4}{r^4+r^2}=0$$
Is my reasoning valid? I am unsure about whether or not the bound for the denominator is correct.

Comment: No: you must find a `lower bound` for the denominator in order to have an `upper bound` for the fraction.

Comment: How do you get your last equality from your trigonometric inequalities?

Comment: @Bernard if I were to find that the lower bound is $1$, would I then be able to say $|r^2\cos^4t+\sin^2t|\ge1$ (which I found with Mathematica) means the limit is equivalent to $\dfrac{3\sqrt3}{16}\lim\limits_{r\to0^+}\dfrac{r^4}{r^2}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$  (x^2 - y)^2 \geq 0,   $$
$$  x^4 - 2 x^2 y + y^2 \geq 0,  $$
$$ x^4 + y^2 \geq 2 x^2 y. $$

$$  (x^2 + y)^2 \geq 0,   $$
$$  x^4 + 2 x^2 y + y^2 \geq 0,  $$
$$ x^4 + y^2 \geq -2 x^2 y. $$

$$ x^4 + y^2 \geq 2 x^2 |y|.  $$

$$ \color{magenta}{ \left| \frac{x^2 y}{x^4 + y^2} \right| \leq \frac{1}{2} }  $$

Your numerator is $x^3 y$ rather than $x^2 y;$ what happens now?

Some detail, not directly needed for your question but probably helpful anyway, at recent [Continuity in $\mathbb R^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1091468/continuity-in-mathbb-rn/1091471#1091471)